# Redirect to different thank you pages on specific shipping method selection

Tags: redirect, woocommerce

I have two different shipping method on my WooCommerce site COD & local pickup, I want to redirect on two different thank you page depending on which shipping method the buyer choose. I tried this but its showing an error after purchase

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;
    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] )) {
        if( $order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate:21') ){
             wp_redirect( 'mysite.com/thank-you-1/' );
             exit;
        }
        elseif( $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup:24') ) {
        wp_redirect( 'mysite.com/thank-you-2/' );
        exit;
    }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: _"I have two different shipping method on my WooCommerce site COD & local pickup"_ - **COD is a payment method**, not a shipping method..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_thankyou`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase');
  
function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if( $order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate:21') ){
        wp_redirect( 'mysite.com/thank-you-1/' );
        exit;
    }elseif( $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup:24') ) {
        wp_redirect( 'mysite.com/thank-you-2/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but it's not working it's redirecting to the default order received page

Comment: What do you get when adding `var_dump($order->get_shipping_methods());die;` after `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`?

Comment: array(1) { [90]=> object(WC_Order_Item_Shipping)#5791 (11) { ["extra_data":protected]=> array(6) { ["method_title"]=> string(0) "" ["method_id"]=> string(0) "" ["instance_id"]=> string(0) "" ["total"]=> int(0) ["total_tax"]=> int(0) ["taxes"]=> array(1) { ["total"]=> array(0) { } } } ["data":protected]=> array(8) { ["order_id"]=> int(227) ["name"]=> string(64) "Free Shipping (upon advance payment via IBFT/)" ["method_title"]=> string(64) "Free Shipping (upon advance payment via IBFT/)" ["method_id"]=> string(13) "free_shipping" ["instance_id"]=> string(2) "24"

Comment: So try replacing `$order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate:21')` with `$order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate')` and for `local_pickup:24` as well

Comment: currently, i have set for flat rate and free shipping and i tried both with flate_rate:21 and free_shipping:24 but its only redirect to the first thank you page if condition isnt working i guess